# Does C++11 require allocators to be default constructible, libstdc++ and libc++ disagree?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, libstdc++, allocator

Using a slightly modified version of [Howard Hinnants's C++11 stack allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h) which is [documented here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11648202/1708801), with `std::basic_string` and compiling with `gcc` which is using `libstdc++`, the following example (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d53788fce6665a7f)*):

```
const unsigned int N = 200;

arena<N> a;
short_alloc<char, N> ac(a) ;

std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,short_alloc<char, N>> empty(ac);
```

gives the following error(*amongst others*):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'short_alloc<char, 200ul>::short_alloc()'
   if (__n == 0 && __a == _Alloc())
                       ^
```

However it works without error when compiling with `clang` and using `libc++` (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ff2950f84a451b4)*).

The `stdlibc++` implementation of `std::basic_string` expects the allocator to have a default constructor.

Does C++11 require allocators to be default constructible? Which implementation is correct?

Comment: Self-answered questions automatically get a downvote. I have a good idea of who it is, but no evidence. Either way, they need to suck it up because the policy on self-answered questions (it's _explicitly encouraged_, and there are even GUI options for it!!) has been linked to them many times but they can't seem to accept that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, C++11 does not require an allocator have default constructor, if we look at the draft C++11 standard section `17.6.3.5` *[allocator.requirements]* it contains Table `28` *Allocator requirements* which does not contain a requirement for a default constructor and later on in the section a minimal conforming interface is provided:

> [ Example: the following is an allocator class template supporting the
>   minimal interface that satisfies the requirements of Table 28:
>
> ```
> template <class Tp>
> struct SimpleAllocator {
>     typedef Tp value_type;
>     SimpleAllocator(ctor args );
>
>     template <class T> SimpleAllocator(const SimpleAllocator<T>& other);
>
>     Tp *allocate(std::size_t n);
>     void deallocate(Tp *p, std::size_t n);
> };
> ```
>
> —end example ]

which does not contain a default constructor.

There is a `libstdc++` bug report: [basic_string assumes that allocators are default-constructible](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56437) which says:

> The empty-string optimization of basic_string assumes that allocators
>   are default constructible. While this used to be the case in C++98, it
>   is no longer true in C++11, as now allocators are allowed to have
>   state.
>
> Consider the attached example program. Compiling with
>
> ```
> g++ -std=c++11 -c t.cpp
> ```
>
> produces an error message, even though it should compile fine. The
>   problem is the the "_S_construct" calls "_Alloc()", which does not
>   exist.
>
> Note that the C++11 standard does not require default constructors.
>   (Section 17.6.3.5, Table 28). In particular, the SimpleAllocator
>   example from Section 17.6.3.5 would trigger the same bug, too.

and the response was:

> This is hardly the only C++11 allocator requirement missing from
>   std::string, ALL of the new requirements are missing, and unlikely to
>   be implemented until we switch to a non-COW string implementation.

This is fixed as of `gcc 5.0`:

> Fixed for GCC 5 (when using the new string ABI)

We can confirm this using [gcc 5 on wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/luTlAV5HglUEjZ5M)